# React-native Expo SpeechOptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I would like to use these expo react native events (onPause, onResume, onDone,...) which can be found here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/speech/#speecheventcallback but I cannot find any correct way to use it. Can anyone please help me with syntax? I haven't found any examples at all.
Thank you
Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const [Playing,setPlaying] = useState(false);
const Text = 'Mom I missed you';
const play = () => {

  Speech.speak(Text,{
      rate:1,
      onStart:() => setPlaying(true), 
      onPause:() => setPlaying(false), 
      onResume:() => setPlaying(true)  
  })

}

return (
  <Button title = 'play' onPress = {play}/>
)
```

Basically on each events(start, resume, pause) respective callback functions will be called..
don't know about **onBoundary** and **onMark**.
basically there is a **boundary** event for SpeechSysthesisUtterance(an api for text to speech for web browsers) maybe **onBoundary** is related to that.

```
//This is only for Web-Apps
  let utt = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello everyone');
  
   utt.addEventListener('boundary' ,(e) => {
          console.log(e.charIndex)
      });

speechSynthesis.speak(utt);
```

e.charIndex is index of Text.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nx_k1XCaWWs
check at 13:30 min

Comment: I have confirmed that the `onBoundary` callback does *not* work for React Native at this time (it does for web). See this [forum post](https://forums.expo.dev/t/expo-speech-onboundary-text-to-speech-callbacks-do-nothing/67346) and this [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@gabrieljoelc/expo-speech-onboundary-does-not-work-on-native-platforms?platform=android) for reproducible example.